# Influence of a data point on the regression result?

Tags: regression

Let's say I perform multiple regression where y = income, x<sub>1</sub> = educaiton, x<sub>2</sub> = sex, and x<sub>3</sub> = religion from 2003 to 2018, where the data is measured daily.

Is there any way to quantify an impact of a single day data (e.x. 2005-07-01) on the regression result?

Comment: With daily data, you can likely expect to see autocorrelation in your model residuals. You can look at the ACF and PACF plots of the model residuals to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Cook's distance (measures influence of a point on the regression equation) - http://www.statisticshowto.com/cooks-distance/